# Can I use logical operator in parameter of hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to add an undefined check before reading some values from `process.env`.

Now consider I'm ensuring that two properties named `"firstConfig"` and `"secondConfig"` existed in `local.settings.json`. And casually I wrote down my code as below:

```js
if(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(process.env, "firstConfig" && "secondConfig")) {
    throw new Error("Something Wrong")
}
// No exception thrown
```

For proving this code, I remove the `"secondConfig"` in `local.settings.json`

```js
if(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(process.env, "firstConfig" && "secondConfig")) {
    throw new Error("Something Wrong")
}
// Exception: Something Wrong
```

So, it seems like this code works correctly, but I cannot find any document to explain it.

Is it valid to use logical operator here if I want to check multiple properties at the same time?

Comment: `Object.property.hasOwnProperty.call(...) && Object.property.hasOwnProperty.call(...)`

Comment: "but I cannot find any document to explain it." --- `"firstConfig" && "secondConfig"` is evaluated and returns `"secondConfig"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: @zerkms Thank you, zerkms... I realize that how stupid questions I've ask :-(

Comment: Don't say that, it's not infrequent that developers try to apply natural language rules to programming. Sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't :-)

Comment: Don't you mean `Object.prototype` instead of `Object.property`?  And, why don't you just use `process.env.hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yep, it's a typo, thanks. Since I'm using TypeScript with ESlint, you can also check out [this article](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-prototype-builtins), it explains that why I don't call `hasOwnProperty()` directly from `process.env` : )

Comment: @TonyDang - That article doesn't really apply here.  This object is of known origin (created internally by nodejs) and it has the `hasOwnProperty` method on it.  There's no reason to overcomplicate your code and to always avoid ALL native object methods.  I would use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call()` only when I was unsure about the origin of the object itself.  Not the case here.  Code doesn't have to be made more complicated than necessary.  If you're worried about someone tinkering with the `process.env` object, then you apparently have much greater problems to worry about.